# Not able to Fetch Options value from Select using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fetch the value of option from select tag but I'm keep getting *Cannot read property 'value' of undefined* below is my HTML and JAVA script code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  displayResult();
});
function displayResult() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("abb_sf_partners-product");
  alert(x[0].options[1].value)
    }
```

```html
<select name="abb_sf_partners-product" data-abb-sf-productelement="" class="abb-select">
   <!--
      <option value="">All products</option>
      -->
   <option value="">All products</option>
   <option value="9AAC100085">Circuit Breakers</option>
   <option value="9AAC910002">Control Systems</option>
   <option value="9AAC100211">Drives</option>
   <option value="9AAC910006">Low Voltage Products and Systems</option>
   <option value="9AAC910019">Measurement and Analytics</option>
   <option value="9AAC173060">Mechanical Power Transmission</option>
   <option value="9AAC720001">Medium Voltage Products and Systems</option>
   <option value="9AAC133417">Motors and Generators</option>
   <option value="9AAC177033">PLC Automation</option>
   <option value="9AAC910011">Robotics</option>
   <option value="9AAC171541">Softstarters</option>
</select>
```

sorry im very new to JavaScript and im not able to proceed any further

in output i required "9AAC100085" if i run this x[0].options[1].value but im getting *Cannot read property 'value' of undefined*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you code runs initially it will attempt to find a value but one is not necessarily selected - hence adding an `onchange` event handler below. The value is deteremined/returned when the user selects a value

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  displayResult();
});


function displayResult() {
  document.querySelector('select[name="abb_sf_partners-product"]').onchange=(e)=>{
    alert(e.target.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="abb_sf_partners-product" data-abb-sf-productelement="" class="abb-select">
   <!--
      <option value="">All products</option>
      -->
   <option value="">All products</option>
   <option value="9AAC100085">Circuit Breakers</option>
   <option value="9AAC910002">Control Systems</option>
   <option value="9AAC100211">Drives</option>
   <option value="9AAC910006">Low Voltage Products and Systems</option>
   <option value="9AAC910019">Measurement and Analytics</option>
   <option value="9AAC173060">Mechanical Power Transmission</option>
   <option value="9AAC720001">Medium Voltage Products and Systems</option>
   <option value="9AAC133417">Motors and Generators</option>
   <option value="9AAC177033">PLC Automation</option>
   <option value="9AAC910011">Robotics</option>
   <option value="9AAC171541">Softstarters</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you so much it resolved my issue :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Perhaps (?) consider `accepting` answers when provided by users if they help '-)